# Psycopg2 "Invalid ELF header"

Tags: sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am trying to create a table using SQLAlchemy and I am getting the error "invalid ELF header".  The path is as follows:

```
venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2-2.6.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/psycopg2/_psycopg.pyd: invalid ELF header
```

One thing to note is I am running this on a Windows PC using the bash shell in a virtual environment (virtualenv), but and had to install the windows executable distribution of Psycopg2 in both my OS and in the virtual environment.  I notice that it says Linux in the path.  Does anyone know what the ELF header is?

Comment: We'll need exact details on your environment. Are you using Bash on Windows (aka Windows Subsystem for Linux, aka lxss) or cygwin/msys? Are you using the LXSS Python, Cygwin Python, or native MSVC-compiled Python? From the error message it sounds like you're mixing environments. ELF is the format for Linux executables. The Windows equivalent is called PE.

Comment: I am using Bash on Window.  Which version of psycopg2 should I install, the Windows version or the Linux version?  I think I installed a windows version but it is calling for the linux version.  I may need to post a separate question about this, because I tried installing the linux version and ran into problems.

Comment: You need the Linux version. I am unsure how you even managed to put the Windows version in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **must not** try to mix architectures whilst installing packages, as many tend to break due to multiple environments on one machine. ELF headers define which architecture to use (ie 64-bit or 32-bit) etc. Therefore, install the Linux version and you should be good to go.